# Problems with rotating array

Tags: python

I get another problem on leetcode. Need to rotate the array, we have a k, where k is a number of steps.

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
```

We need to move last 3 numbers to the another side.
I made this:

```
def rotate(nums: list, k: int):
    a = nums[:-k]
    b = nums[-1:k:-1]
    b.reverse()
    res = b + a
    return res
```

And it works in pycharm, my output is `[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, but in leetcode is says that my output is kinda sorted or something like this. Idk but it says that output is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. Can u guys tell me where is the problem pls))

Comment: why not just slice? `nums[-k:] + nums[:-k]`

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the [description](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/) of the problem my guess would be that instead of modifying the array in place you return a new object and the original array is unmodified. While problem description states:

```
Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you wanted in place change..! your res is correct but you are not changing nums..! you wanted to change nums..

```
def rotate(nums: List[int], k: int):
         
    #To Rotate Right
    n=len(nums)
    k=k%n
    nums[:]=[*nums[-k:],*nums[:-k]] #change in nums in place
    
    #To rotate left
    #n=len(nums)
    #k=k%n
    #nums[:]=[*nums[k:],*nums[:k]] #change in nums in place
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]    
n = 4
list_1 = (list_1[len(list_1) - n:len(list_1)] + list_1[0:len(list_1) - n])
print(list_1)
```